# check if a List contains elements of another list

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Assuming there is a result [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) `R`, and an expected List `E`.

```
List<String> R = ...
List<String> E = ...
```

How can I use JUnit's `assertTrue(…)` to check that `R` contains at least all elements in `E`?

Comment: Javadoc is your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method [`containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) of the [`List`-Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) does exactly that

```
assertTrue(R.containsAll(E));
```

Comment: @user842225 Are you sure all elements of E are contained in R? Can you provide us your unit test in the OP?

Comment: @user842225 the JVM implementation of containsAll surely works fine. Are you sure about the List containing exactly the same Strings? The contains-method uses the equals-method and the equals method of String compares the Strings exactly (case sensitive!)

Answer (score 1):

Try [containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) method of List like:

```
assertTrue(R.containsAll(E));
```